# Clearing cookies in webkit webview React Native

Tags: react-native, cookies

UIWebView has officially been deprecated on iOS (and has horrible performance), so it seems using webkit webview is the only option now. However, the react-native-cookies library (https://github.com/joeferraro/react-native-cookies) has not yet added support for clearing cookies in webkit webview (it is on their master branch and in their docs but not published to npm).
Does anyone know an alternative to this library or a way of doing this yourself? When googling the issue it seems like everyone uses this library for cookie management, so I figure other people might have had this issue as well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You didn't read the documentation didn't you  ? https://github.com/joeferraro/react-native-cookies#webkit-support-ios-only